# Is there a reason why I am getting a NullPointerException when using user.reauthenticate(authCredential).addOnSuccessListener and how can I fix it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, nullpointerexception

When I use this AuthCredential, it keeps throwing the null pointer exception, I used try/catch block but it just catches it and I tried if(user!=null), I have already initialized the variables earlier in the scope so I do not think it is an issue with the ID

```java
user.reauthenticate(authCredential).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
```

I tried a try/catch block but that just catches the exception, I tried the `if(user!=null)` and I have already declared the EditText earlier in the program as

Comment: If `user` is not null, the the outcome of `user.reauthenticate(authCredential)` is probably null.

Comment: Show us how you have initiated the variable.